# Exclude "H:m"in dateTimeLabel Highcharts

Tags: javascript, date, highcharts

How to exclude the "H:m" in my label?

[image: My label]

Comment: Can post your code, pls?

Comment: the code of Label  xAxis: {
         
              dateTimeLabelFormats:{
                hour: '%H',
              }
        },

Comment: but I want to take it off

Answer (score 2):

Use `dateTimeLabelFormats` under tooltip object: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.date

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4NFW/